# I have a macro to add a new tab but want that new tab to have a worksheet specific macro added, within the original macro

Tags: vba, excel

Original macro adds new tab called List, but on the new tab ("List") I want a sheet specific macro that changes cell color when cell is clicked (which I have already written).

Does anyone know of any hints? I haven't found anything.

Comment: You can use the workbook_SheetChange handler of the ThisWorkbook object, this means you only have the macro once and it works for whichever sheets you want

Answer (score -1):

in project window select worksheet you need

write:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Selection.Interior.Color = vbRed 'color you need
End Sub
```

thats it, you don't need any macro